# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Moving nodes in mirrored environment

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore, mirroring

Was hoping that I would find this documented somewhere, but I've searched and searched. Finally asking the question myself:

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 in a HA setup (primary/mirror/witness)

I want to move the mirror and witness servers to different hardware from what they're currently on.

It's only 1 db and about 20GB in size, it uses SQL authentication for the db (not Windows auth) and the Windows SQL service will run with the same domain user on all nodes.

I assume I start by installing SQL Server on the new nodes, and adding the endpoints to each instance.

From there would I just remove mirroring from the primary instance and re-create mirroring, adding the new nodes? Would I need to restore from a backup on the new mirror instance?

Hopefully someone can lay out the steps involved, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct..

1. Install SQL Server on the new nodes
2. Use [SP_HELP_REVLOGIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) to copy the user account to the secondary node
3. Take a full backup and a single log backup of the primary server and restore on the secondary with no_recovery
4. Break the mirror and remove the secondaries from the primary server
5. Create the endpoints with TSQL or use the Mirroring wizard to configure them and endpoint security
6. start mirroring

Comment: Hello and thank you. Can you please confirm that when recovering, first recovery the full backup without the no_recovery option, after that's finished, restore the transaction logs, with the "no_recovery" option?

Comment: Yes, both backup should be restored with the no_recovery option and the database should be in the (recovering) state when you start the replication